# VBA Excel - Using a variable to determine cell location

Tags: vba, excel

I don't exactly know how to formulate my question since so I'll just give an example which should make it clear.

Basically I want to use a variable to determine what cell I have to use.
For example, I count the amount of rows my sheet has and store it in a variable. Now I want to use that variable to determine a range.

```
Range("K2:M*").Select
```

Now where I have the * I want to use the rows I counted and stored in a variable earlier on.

How can I do this?

Comment: `Range("K2:M" & variable).Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach to such things is using the alternate form of Range's arguments, the one with cells. Why? because is really easier to dealing with numerically-indexed columns than the "A1" type of address. For example:

```
Dim col1 As Long
Dim row1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
Dim row2 As Long

' Some code to initialize/calculate
Let col1 = 11 'K
Let row1 = 2
Let col2 = 13 'M
Let row2 = SomeFunctionThatCalculates()

With Worksheets("Whatever") ' Replace with a valid Worksheet object
        Call .Range( _
           .Cells(row1,col1), _
           .Cells(row2,col2) _
        ).Select
End With
```

Of course, for rows a quick way is the one given by Rory in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
sub Test()
Dim Var1 as string

Var1 = 'Whatever your variable is

Range("K2:M" & Var1).select

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was to how to get the range of the worksheet selected with the ability to scale to the bottom of the sheet, excluding headers - thus starting with 2:bottom. i tend to use the usedrange property.

```
sub test
    dim rowcount as double
    rowcount = activesheet.usedrange.rows.count

    Range("K2:M" & rowcount).Select
    end sub
```